# Can I call next callback twice?

Tags: javascript, express

I want to do some logging in the application. The flow I'm currently think is I pass a middleware function to my other middleware, then called the middleware function inside it.

I know it might be confusing, but this is the case I'm having now, I already have error logging middleware but want to invoke it later when on response `finish`

```
//middleware that called other middleware

module.exports = function(loggingMiddleware) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    res.on("finish", () => {
      loggingMiddleware(req, res, next) // will be called twice here
    }
    next() // to other middleware
  }
}
```

My concern is, is it ok to call the next twice?

Comment: Why are you doing this ? is it because you want to execute loggingMiddlewareafter at the end of every middleware  ?

Comment: @krishnasapkal want to execute loggingMiddleware after the response has been sent

Comment: I think if you call the next in the loggingMiddleware the last next never going to be called.

Comment: why don't you put your loggingMiddleware after the response and  call next()   ?

Comment: @krishnasapkal becauseI thought this more convenient than having to call next after the response send? We do have to call next if we want to advance to next middleware right?

Comment: yes, we do have to call next  to advance to next middleware. I can't understand why this is convinient. :P